# Не ловится OSError

Tags: python, python-3.x, исключения, ос

Написал программу, которая будет переименовывать файлы, запущенные с её помощью.
Добавил конструкцию try/except, которая будет отлавливать OSError при использовании символов, которыми нельзя называть файл. Но при попытке назвать файл запрещенным именем приложение всё равно крашится с OSError. Не пойму, где я ошибся

```
if newName:
    for i, f in enumerate(args):
        dir = os.path.dirname(f)
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))
        fName = newName + '_' + str(i+1).zfill(3) + ext
        fullPath = os.path.join(dir, fName)
        try:
            os.rename(f, fullPath)
        except OSError:
            print('Недопустимое имя файла!')
            break
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12373611/7927226 - может быть полезно

Answer (score 1):

Код в вопросе рабочий, исключение ловится (оно и не может не пойматься). Возможно, автор ошибся.

```
import os

try:
    os.rename('C:/a$?^bc123.txt', 'C:/:?`abc321.txt')
except OSError as e:
    print(e)
    print('Недопустимое имя файла!')
```

Консоль:

> [WinError 123] Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или
> метке тома: 'C:/a$?^bc123.txt' -> 'C:/:?`abc321.txt' Недопустимое имя
> файла!